# How do I make sure a nested form group returns an array of objects in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular14

I am working on a form with *nested form groups* in Angular 14.

In `form.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
})
export class FormComponent {
  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    first_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    last_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),

    residences: new FormGroup({
      city: new FormControl(''),
      address: new FormControl(''),
    }),
  });

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  public sendFormData() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

See Stackblitz **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-mnstsm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)**.

#### The problem

I need `residences` to be an *array of objects*. Instead, it is an *object itself*.

###### How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a form array:

```js
  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    first_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    last_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),

    residences: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        city: new FormControl(''),
        address: new FormControl(''),
      }),
    ]),
  });

  get residencesArray(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('residences') as FormArray;
  }
```

In the template:

```html
  <div
    formArrayName="residences"
    *ngFor="let residence of residencesArray.controls; let i = index"
  >
    Residence {{ i + 1 }}
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label class="mat-label">City:</mat-label>
        <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="city" />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label class="mat-label">Address:</mat-label>
        <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="address" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-xg26ar?file=src/app/form/form.component.html)

Comment: I don't want 2 buttons. just one should work, like **[this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-n2syev?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.ts)**. Thanks!

Comment: It was to show how to dynamically add form groups to a form array.